# SCP file from ssh session to localhost

Tags: macos, bash, ssh, sftp, scp

I have a headless file server on which I store and manage downloads and media, but occasionally I have to transfer small files back to my computer (Mac, using bash shell). The problem is that some files have more user-friendly names and commonly have spaces in them, and they are buried in the file directory hierarchy I have set up on my server.

When I'm using `scp` from my local machine, I don't have tab completion, so I have to manually type out the entire path and name with spaces escaped. When I `ssh` into the server first, the command:

```
scp /home/me/files/file\ name\ with\ spaces.png Me@localhost:/Users/Me/MyDirectory
```

fails with the error "Permission denied, please try again" even though I'm entering my local machine user password properly.

I've learned a little bit of `sftp` since I've been told that may be a better tool for file transfer. However, the utility seems outdated and I still don't have tab completion after establishing a connection to the server (on my Terminal when pressing `Tab` I just get a tab character).

My question is this: what can I do to allow tab completion while using `scp` from my Mac? Or am I using incorrect syntax for `scp` while in an `ssh` session, and is there something in that command I should fix? Or, is there a (better? newer?) tool other than sftp that would offer tab completion on a server?

Finally, if none of these problems have simple solutions, is there some package I could install (e.g. a completion package from Homebrew or the like) that would facilitate better tab-completion with any of these commands?

Comment: You like 3D Printing? Check out [3D Printing on SE](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/) :D

Comment: @MattClark Yeah, I built a RepRap i3 last year. Thanks for the tip, I'll definitely check it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like this is some incorrect `scp`ing.

This is the format of the command

```
scp ./localFile.txt remoteUser@remoteHost:/remoteFile.txt
```

You were so close, but you have `localhost` set where you should have your `remoteHost`.

`localhost` is the name that resolves to the machine that you are currently on - so in your workflow, you are `ssh`ing to a machine, and then trying to `scp` that file to the same machine you are already `ssh`d into.

What you need to do, is figure out the IP address, or the physical host name of the computer that you are trying to connect to, and use that instead.

```
scp ./localFile.txt remoteUser@192.168.1.100:/remoteFile.txt
# where 192.168.1.100 would be the IP of your Mac
```

I am assuming the reason you were getting permission denied, was because you were using your the login credentials for you mac, but unknowingly trying to login again to your headless machine.

Comment: Ah I feel silly about `localhost` now. However when I fix it to `Me@192.168.1.xxx` after finding my local IP, I get the error `ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.xxx port 22: Connection refused`. I don't have `sshd` running on my Mac (after using `ps` to look for it) but I'm not sure of where to proceed from here...

Comment: Sounds like you should install `sshd` on your Mac :p

Comment: ^ Ha. That would do it. For posterity, no need to install `sshd` : on a Mac you just need to enable Remote Logins in System Preferences > Sharing.